# Can't connect to my docker host postgresql database from a container

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, networking, fedora

If I do `ifconfig`, `docker0` ip is `172.17.0.1` and when I run my containerized app and then `docker network inspect bridge` myapp ip is `172.17.0.2`, they are on the same network I suppose.

But inside myapp I am trying to connect to my docker host's postgresql database, I provide `172.17.0.1:5432` to my ORM but it throws an error `connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.1:5432`.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Which OS do you use? Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: @KitHsu I am using Fedora 27

Comment: I guess that the PostgreSQL is installed on the host rather than in a container. If I'm right, we should assure that PostgreSQL works well and also listens on docker0. The typical way to probe port liveness is to run **nc -v 172.17.0.1 5432** on the host or **netstat -np | grep 5432** to see the port state. If the port is alive, try to disable SELinux.

Comment: I have disabled SELinux and also postgresql is perfectly running fine on port `5432`, i really don't see the issue. It looks like the container is blocking connection on this port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add `listen_addresses="*"` in `postgresql.conf` ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19559391)

Comment: @DerekBrown this does provide an answer to the question. Because my question features an issue and this is how it fixes the issue I had.

Answer (score 2):

check your pg_hba.conf file in the data directory of your postgres instance. In this file you configure which users are allowed to authenticate through which network. Make sure your postgres instance is accepting connections from the docker0 network by adding the following line:

```
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/24            md5
```

in this line you could adjust the second 'all' to specify a certain user.

Comment: Ok so I found the reason why it was not working, thanks for your answer, my postgresql installation was accepting md5 from all connections but I didn't use `listen_addresses="*"` in my `postgresql.conf`...